# Generate multiple tag query URLs

Tags: permalinks, multi-taxonomy-query, advanced-taxonomy-queries

As we know WordPress supports multiple tag queries (',' and '+'). The only problem with this `add_query_arg()` doesn't handle these methods if a query param is already exists in the URL.

From the following url `www.domain.com?post_type=ptype&param=value1 add_query_arg('param', 'value2')` will generate `www.domain.com?post_type=ptype&param=value2` insead of `www.domain.com?post_type=ptype&param=value1,value2` or `value1+value2`

I would only use comma separated (OR) method. Could you please help me to write a function which adds additional param value next to an exsisting one? regular expressions perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url = parse_url( $your_url );
$query = $url['query'];

$args_arr = array();
parse_str( $query, $args_arr );

if( isset( $args_arr['param'] ) ) {
    $query_string = $args_arr['param'];
    $query_string .= ',value2';
} else {
    $query_string = 'value2';
}

add_query_arg( 'param', $query_string );
```

That's completely untested, but you get the concept. Basically, wordpress is gonna want to replace what you have set in `param`, so you need to get what you have in param, then add what you want to add to it. You can definitely make that into a function if you want to, depends on your usage case.